# with matchit installed %match parenthesis and brackets only once in Fortran files

Tags: delimiter-matching, plugin-matchit, filetype-fortran

At the moment I'm writing, I removed the `matchit` plugin and the `%` works well, making the cursor jump from a `(`, `[`, or `{` to the corresponding closing character and vice versa.

Now I installed `matchit` again, adding `Plugin 'vim-scripts/matchit.zip'` to my `.vimrc` and then running Vundle's `:PluginInstall`. Having done so, I can now jump back and forth from `subroutine` to `end subroutine` in my `.f90` files and so on (and I can do it with `.cpp` and so on).

**But** I cannot make this jumps with parenthesis and brackets and other "standard" pairs.

I have no idea what could be the reason of such strange behavior in Vim. I hope the following observations can be useful for you to help me.

- Wherever I press `%` (to jump between a standard or non standard pair, or on an empty line with no reason), then I cannot use it anymore, as well as the cursor remains in the buffer related to a `.f90` file.
- If I move to another buffer/window related to a NON `.f90` file (by `:n<CR>`, `:N<CR>`, `<C-W><C-W>` and so on, or simply `:help<CR>`) **and** press `%` at least once (to jump between ... as before), then I can go back to a `.f90` buffer/window and use `%` with standard pairs once (just **once**!) again.
- Jumping between new pairs (`IF`, `DO`, and so on) is not affected.

Maybe I should underline that I got the feeling that this happens only with Fortran files (`.f90` and `.f95`), since it doesn't happen with help pages (`.txt`) nor with `.cpp` files.

Comment: I don't know the `vim-script/matchit.zip` plugin you're talking about but in my `.vimrc` I have `runtime macros/matchit.vim` which enables the defaut matchit plugin and `%` works on brackets as well as on `subroutine` maybe you should try that.

Comment: On [GitHub](https://github.com/vim-scripts/matchit.zip) I read "Since vim 6.0, matchit.vim has been included in the standard vim distribution, under the macros/ directory; the version here may be more recent.". Anyway I followed your advice. Still I have exactly the same behavior.

Comment: Oh well using the up to date version souds like a good idea indeed. Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem so I can't help you more than that.

Comment: `:h matchit.txt` and especially `:h matchit-debug`. The Github mirror is older then the distributed version with Vim.

Comment: make sure to enable filetype plugins and check the `b:match_words` variable and also your matchpairs setting.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, matching with matchit works only once and then not anymore? I think this was fixed with a recent runtime file update

Comment: Perfect, in term of solution. I just typed `:MatchDebug<CR>` and everything works. Obviously I needed to put `MatchDebug` in my `.vimrc`. Anyway I have no idea of why and how it works. In the help tag you linked I understood that `:MatchDebug` is meant to create variables and help debugging, so how can it solve my problem (it does!). Am I wrong? Please, post an answer.

Comment: I think [this commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/06d2d38ab7564e1f784b1058) fixed the problem.

Comment: Can't you post your answer? If you do, than I can accept, and the question is no more un-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [that](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/06d2d38ab7564e1f784b1058) provided by @ChristianBrabandt.